# Override public field javascript prototype

Tags: javascript

I simply try to override the fields and functions from Car class. How to override existent fields and functions?

```
Car = function()
{
    this.doors = null;
    this.open = function(){alert("open it!");}
}

Car.prototype.doors = 4;

Car.prototype.open = function(){ // public method
    alert("do not open!");
}

myCar = new Car();
alert(myCar.doors); //null?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, `prototype` is not some magic trick allowing you to extend an object. Its only purpose is to serve values for properties not found in the corresponding object. Here, both `doors` and `open` are defined for a `Car` object, that's why any look-up won't even reach `Car.prototype`.

And that's easy to prove: just add these lines to your code

```
delete myCar.doors;
alert(myCar.doors); // 4
```

Explanation: with `delete myCar.doors` the corresponding property is *removed* from an object. When you look-up for its value in the next line, it goes up the prototype chain, reaching `Car.prototype.doors` - which value is set to 4.

That's why, btw, `prototype chain` is rarely used for setting static values for a specific class. But it's very useful for setting up so-called class methods, as only a single copy of a function will be created and stored in memory.

Comment: Yes, unless property of an object is defined as `read-only`, you can freely assign any value to it.

Comment: @raina77ow so prototype is there for append, not for extend

Comment: I'd say prototype allows to set some default values for an object, but only if these properties are NOT set in that object. Note that you rarely should update prototype's properties' values once set.